# FacialFeatures returning no results!

Tags: warning-messages, resourceobject

[image]

The above is an example in the documentation.

I run it, but it doesn't work!

What should I do?

Comment: This requires some initial download of data from Wolfram repository(approx 100 MB). Make sure you are on an active internet connection.

Comment: I have been connected, but there is no hint of download. How can I download data manually?

Comment: Please post code rather than screenshots: easier to copy paste (and less space storing data...)

Answer (score 8):

Quoting from the documentation of `FacialFeatures` introduced in MMA 11.3:

> `FacialFeatures` may download resources that will be stored in your local object store at `$LocalBase`, and that can be listed using `LocalObjects[]` and removed using `ResourceRemove`.

I couldn't get `ResourceRemove` to work but you can still try the following:

First, clear the data already downloaded by locating the particular resource folder under *Resources* inside the directory `$LocalBase$`. On my PC it was *6a8*. It may or may not have the same name in yours. You can try to choose your resource folder by checking the time-stamp of last modification. Now, once you have located the folder, proceed to first delete it.

```
DeleteObject[LocalObjects["/Resources/6a8"]]
```

Then open a new session to clear the existing cache containing the resource data.

Now, re-evaluate your code. This will force a re-download from the Wolfram servers. Just ensure that you have a stable enough internet connection this time.

Comment: I deleted the resource data "6a8" in the folder.It's amzing.My problem have been solved.Thank you very much!

Comment: @yonghui wang Happy to help!

Comment: Same problem (v11.3.0), same ressource name ("6a8"), solved by your `DeleteObject` command. However it seems it did not work until I removed the first "/" in the command, i.e: `DeleteObject[LocalObjects["Resources/6a8"]]` ...

Comment: @SquareOne Both should be fine. I don't know why putting the first slash didn't work.